# Null value passed as string "null" from listBox with no selection

Tags: google-apps-script

I am checking that a user makes a selection from a listbox. It appears that if no selection is made, the value passed to the server handler is "null" NOT null. Is this working as intended?

This code correctly tests for no selection in selectList listBox.

```
    Logger.log("e.parameter.selectList"+e.parameter.selectList)
if (e.parameter.selectList === "null") {
 error = true;
 errortext = "no valid region selected";
 Logger.log('error')
}
```

I expected

```
    if (!e.parameter.selectList )... to work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is known. 
All the values in the handler are returned as string (except the dateBox value, I am not sure though). E.g checkbox value is returned "true"/"false" not true/false (a boolean value). You will have to parse these strings first to get the values in the desired form.
I usually use `Utilities.jsonParse(stringValue)`

Comment: I can confirm that dateBox is indeed an exception and returns a date object, not a string. I just tested this using the following code without error :  ’var date = e.parameter.date;
  date.setHours(e.parameter.hour,e.parameter.min,0)’

Comment: So the behaviour is not consistent. Is it "working as intended" though? Or is someone going to fix it and break the code of people who have just worked around a daft implementation?

Comment: @DavidF It will be good if you report this issue in Issue Tracker.https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list